# How to setup CI for my application with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a scheduled build in Jenkins which runs everyday at 12:00 AM. I want to set up a CI server for my project. I want to set it such a way that before every build, my application is undeployed and once the build is successful, it's deployed and up again, running on the server. This is possible if I manually add some server in my system and put the shell command in pre-build and post-build actions to undeploy and deploy manually but is it possible directly with Jenkins? As the name suggests, Jenkins - CI server, is there any way how can I do it with Jenkins?

Note: I have maven jetty plugin and have set a goal `clean install jetty:run` in my application but it doesn't suit my requirement in Jenkins for CI server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jenkins will run any script at any time, so you can do this very easily. You don't need to use pre- and post-build actions. Build steps work very well for this use. You can add multiple steps to a single Jenkins job/project.